# How to save data signal from black to tablet Samsung using SQLITE database android... the incoming data is byte

Tags: android, sqlite, android-bluetooth

I am a newbie in Android Development. and I want to get data signal between RFdata device and Samsung tab and create a database of the output.
Can someone share the  code(even if just  how to process).I am using bluetoothchat code but am not able to store the data on my computer.Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.
My regards.